# GHC FFI on windows: undefined reference to `CreateInstance@4'

Tags: haskell

I have a super basic test module to try to use a windows DLL:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Fface where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

newtype FFACE = FFACE (Ptr FFACE)

foreign import stdcall unsafe "FFACE4.h CreateInstance"
    c_CreateInstance :: CUInt -> IO (Ptr FFACE)
```

When trying to compile it into a simple test program I get the following error:

```
Linking Main.exe ...
.\Fface.o:fake:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `CreateInstance@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using gendef to dump the export list from the DLL I see that the function is actually exported as "CreateInstance@1925", but almost all of the other functions are exported as just their plain name with no @number stuff.  What is the @1925 for, and how can I get GHC to use that instead of @4?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but one way to side-step odd linker errors is to use dynamic loading. See my Win32-dhcp-server library's [System.Win32.DHCP.Internal](https://github.com/mikesteele81/Win32-dhcp-server/blob/master/System/Win32/DHCP/Internal.hs) module for an example.